# variable class name for css

Tags: css, class, variables, sass

What I want is pretty simple:

I want to be able to use classnames like: class-5, class-8, etc.

In the css(scss), a variable should be able to pick up the numbers:

```
.class-x{
    font-size: rem-calc(x);
}
```

Is something like this at all possible(because that would be awesome)?

Comment: Using pure CSS at current implementation level in browsers, I’d say no. Using a CSS pre-processor like LESS or SASS, it might be …

Comment: If not using LESS and SASS you can use javascript to achieve it

Comment: If you know you might need to use Sass for this, why didn't you try [looking at the Sass documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#_9) first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I's possible if you have a limited number of `x` :

```
@for $i from 1 through 10 {
  .class-#{$i} {
    font-size: rem-calc($i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a sass array of numbers you want to use, then loop through to build up the output for each index;

```
$numbers: 3, 5, 8, 9, 12, 15;
@each $i in $numbers {
  .class-#{$i} {
    font-size: rem-calc($i);
  }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://sassmeister.com/gist/550f140d24fe615d20f8)**